# Write special web program in several OS System(Desktop, Android, IOS)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, web

I want to write a program can use in desktop, Android and IOS, I study Cordova and I think that we can use Cordova for this, can I use Cordova for this matter, if I use Cordova, In any operating System, can I use special API, for example I use Cordova in android for my program, Can I use Android API in my project, I use both of them (Cordova, Android API)? 
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to create the app for multiple platforms, then just use html5, don't use anything specific to android, i don't believe you can use anything specific to android, because it all gets put in a webView, Cordova should supply the necessary items, i.e filesystem, networking, etc..

Also you can build it up with Angular, or any other similar framework, and use Bootstrap, ionic, or similar UI libraries to normalise the look.

Comment: Thank you for your answering, if i use html5 , can i use another libraries?Is it is good performance in several OS?Can i have good UI in several devices for example types of the several android devices or ios?

Comment: If you use something like this: ionicframework.com it will like the same on all platforms, and yes, you can use 3rd party html5 libraries as much as you want, I'm working with Cordova for work, and its consistant

Comment: No Problem! have fun :)

Comment: thank you, the 3rd party is on my os, how the 3rd party can connect to HTML? can it?

Comment: I meant 3rd party HTML, not iOS, or Android, like UIBootstrap, you're basically making a site.